# Remove reference $id from json object list in WebApi

Tags: c#, json, api, json.net, serialization

I would like to change my response data format from

```
{
    "$id": "1",
    "$values": [
        {
            "$id": "2",
            "OrderID": 3,
            "Article": null
        },
        {
            "$id": "3",
            "OrderID": 4,
            "Article": null
        }
     ]
}
```

to

```
 [
    {
        "OrderID": 3,
        "Article": null
    },
    {
        "OrderID": 4,
        "Article": null
    }
 ]
```

I tried configuring JsonFormatter in WebApiConfig.cs file adding these two lines

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.None;
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
```

but doesn't work.

Controller code is this and its class inherit from ApiController

```
    public List<OrderDto> Get()
    {
        var serviceResult = orderService.LoadOrders();

        if (serviceResult.IsValid)
        {
            var orders = serviceResult.GetObject();

            var ordersDto = Mapper.Map<List<Order>, List<OrderDto>>(orders);

            return ordersDto;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Any idea for this solution?

Edit 1:

OrderDto.cs code

```
public class OrderDto
{
    public int OrderID { get; set; }

    public string Article { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: can you provide your OrderVM code?

Comment: @AnonymousCodes answered

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. I believe that if you are using Web API, to clarify the types of actions you should decorate them with attributes e.g. `[HttpGet]`, `[HttpPost]` etc.
2. I would use `Dtos` objects instead of `ViewModel` objects when using the API because it is not purely MVC architecture and many clients can use your API using different ways.
3. I would rather return a BadRequest response `Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "error message")` with some error message in your else statement instead of `null`. This would be a quick solution however I would think about throwing exceptions in the implementation of your service and based on this return proper error message back to the client.

This should work:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage GetAllOrders()
{
    //var serviceResult = orderService.LoadOrders();
    // var isValid = serviceResult.IsValid
    var isValid = true;
    if (isValid)
    {
        // I used hardcoded values here just to show how to return a proper result
        // you can call your service instead and do the mapping/other stuff

        var result = new List<OrderDto>()
        {
            new OrderDto(){
                OrderID = 3,
                Article = "blah1"
            },
            new OrderDto(){
                OrderID = 4,
                Article = "blah2"
            }
        };
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
    }
    else
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Error Message");

    }
}

public class OrderDto
{
    public int OrderID { get; set; }

    public string Article { get; set; }
}
```

the WebApiConfig.cs content:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Web API configuration and services

    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );

    var appXmlType = config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.MediaType == "application/xml");
    config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Remove(appXmlType);
}
```

**The result**

when `var isValid = true;`

[image]

when `var isValid = false;`

[image]

Comment: Nope. Your code is from .NET MVC project and not from .NET WebApi project. 
In .NET WebApi project controllers don't response ActionResult object. WebApi projects response HttpActionResult object instead.

My OrderVM object works in the same way as your OrderDto object.

Comment: Sry I was to quick IActionResult was from .net core. Actual solution is for .net framework

Comment: I have changed my code from yours but the result is the same =/

Comment: If I decorate my OrderDto.cs class with [JsonObject(IsReference = false)] I can remove $id attribute from json order objects, but not the first $id and $values from response

Comment: try now please and if still doesnt work can you please add the code from your `WebApiConfig` `Register` method?

Comment: ^ I meant whole content of WebApiConfig

Comment: Sorry mate... I had in my global.asax this code after register WebApiConfig...
    
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.All;

I remove that line and now everything works...

Comment: Hehe sometimes it happens :) I hope that maybe my tips will be useful. Happy coding. Cheers ;)